# ASP.NET Web API и Angular - ошибка 405

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular2, asp.net-web-api, spa

В общем имеется развернутое Web API на IIS 8 с Angular 2 SPA. При использовании метода POST (попытка залогиниться) выдает 405 ошибку, что Htttp verb not allowed. CORS подключен и работает, что видно по данным из fidler:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам CORS подключил в web.config, ну и WebDAV удалил там же (как выглядит web.config):

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://codesurvey.r-mobile.pro/api" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,PATCH" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="*" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
<handlers>
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <remove name="WebDAV" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
<modules>
    <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
</modules>
```

Колдую над этим делом уже неделю, не могу понять почему не работает. Помогите разобраться, молю :(